# react-native run-android with param to run Android emulator as well

Tags: react-native

I'm running React Native project for iOS like
`react-native run-ios --simulator="iPhone 8"`
so it runs a specific simulator automatically.

Is there any way to do the same for Android?

Comment: If you are using expo, then you can use `expo start`. And then, run with emulator

Comment: thanks, the question isn't about expo

Answer (score -1):

First launch emulator in which you want to run app. Using terminal you can launch by following command :

> emulator -avd [avd-name]

Then simply run `react-native run-android --emulator="AVD-NAME"` command.

Comment: thanks for the answer, I know how to run an android emulator. I'm curious is there way to run it with one command like for iOS something like `react-native run-android --emulator="Emulator Name"`

Comment: I got `error: unknown option `--emulator'`. Is it working for you?

Comment: try to replace --emulator to --device

Comment: Same error `error: unknown option `--device'`. Where did you find those params?

Comment: @Dmitri Portenko you can find with react-native run-android --help. In my case it was  --deviceId

Comment: @algae514 nice, super helpful. It will not run emulator but still super useful information.